# ASP.NET MVC SMTPClient not working on hosted environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp, smtpclient

When I run my application locally on localhost, the e-mail is sent out successfully with no exceptions. But when I publish the application and try to re-create the e-mail it does not send the e-mail nor sends the View with the corresponding error.

```
try
{
    using (var mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        const string email = "*******@gmail.com";
        const string password = "*********";
        var loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
        mail.From = new MailAddress("*******@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("email@email.com"));
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        try
        {
            using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
            {
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtpClient.Credentials = loginInfo;
                smtpClient.Send(mail);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            mail.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)
{
    foreach (SmtpFailedRecipientException t in ex.InnerExceptions)
    {
        var status = t.StatusCode;
        if (status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy ||
            status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable)
        {
            return View(status);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(status);
        }
    }

}
catch (SmtpException Se)
{
    // handle exception here
    return View(Se);
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    return View(ex);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program on the server? Or adding logging so you can see exactly the path the code takes?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not displayed here, however, it is possible that is a client authentication error.
Please try:

1. Login into your gmail account
2. Allow the IP of your hosting under gmail settings
3. Retry sending the email

Another thing to note, you do not need to try .. finally on your MailMessage() object.  Since it is already wrapped in a using statement, when it reaches the end of the using block is will dispose it for you and any errors will get caught in your outer try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all that exception handling, and try again. Find out what the error is, then go from there.

I suspect the reason youre having a hard time is b/c of the way you have your try/catch's set up. The inner try/catch strikes me as being a little odd.